# how to derive season in a date dimension

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm implementing a DataWarehouse date dimension. According to my scenario I have to mark days between October and January as `Season_A` and days between April and August as `Season_B`.

I have created the `dimDate` table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.dimDate
(
DateKey INT NOT NULL,
FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
MonthNumberName NVARCHAR(15) NULL,
CalendarQuarter TINYINT NULL,
CalendarYear SMALLINT NULL,
Season NVARCHAR(10) 
CONSTRAINT PK_Dates PRIMARY KEY (DateKey)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baring other concerns / factors, my initial reaction to this would be to use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) and calculate the Season using a simple between clause in the stored procedure

Sample Implementation pseudo-code

---

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.dimDate 
( 
   DateKey INT NOT NULL
  ,FullDate DATE NOT NULL
  ,MonthNumberName NVARCHAR(15) NULL
  ,CalendarQuarter TINYINT NULL
  ,CalendarYear SMALLINT NULL
  ,Season NVARCHAR(10) as GetSeason(FullDate)
  ,CONSTRAINT PK_Dates PRIMARY KEY (DateKey) 
);
GO;

Create Procedure dbo.GetSeason
    @Date as datetime
as
   if(Month(@Date) between 1 and 3)
      select 'Season A'
   --etc
```

To be completely honest, my experience has been that dimDate tables should pretty much have ALL columns computed off a single date column (ie: FullDate key) to prevent data inconsistency during ETL processing but others mileage may vary...

Comment: Thank you for the support. In my scenario season_B belongs to two years as it falls on Oct-January. So I want to store that information and so I added another column call "SeasonYear". Can you please help me to populate that column.
eg: (19900101, 1990-01-01, 01, 1, 1990, Season_B, 1989-1990)